# Threaded socket function messing up local variables

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am making a tiny test server in Python, using TCP. The sockets are blocking, but I dont think the sockets are relevant for this question. I know the current solution is a bit ugly and messy but it is after lots of testing and tweaking to see what works and what doesnt.

This function is run in a thread for each client, inside a class.

Each Client(a class) holds a name and some other non-relevant stuff which are set earlier.

The problem is that whenever I have two or more clients connected the client variable is set to the last added client, in this case Computer2. Also you can see that the index variable is never affected.

Here's the code:

```
def recieveDataFromClient(self, sock, index):
    while True:
        client = self.clients[index]
        recvStr = sock.recv(1024).decode()
        if not recvStr:
            break
        if client.name:
            print("got something from "+client.name+" on "+str(sock))
            print("Clients:")
            for client in self.clients:
                print(client.name)
            print("this client is: "+str(index)+" - "+self.clients[index].name+" aka "+client.name)
```

Here's the output, when sent from Computer1:

```
got something from Computer1 on <socket.socket object, fd=1044, family=2, type=1, proto=0>
Clients:
Computer1
Computer2
this client is: 0 - Computer1 aka Computer2
```

Here's the output, when sent from Computer2:

```
got something from Computer2 on <socket.socket object, fd=1100, family=2, type=1, proto=0>
Clients:
Computer1
Computer2
this client is: 1 - Computer2 aka Computer2
```

Comment: Your indentation appears incorrect. Can you fix it, or confirm that what we see is what you really have?

Comment: Fixed now, accidently removed a tab when pasting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're accidentally overwriting the `client` variable:

```
  client = self.clients[index]  # You assign client here
    recvStr = sock.recv(1024).decode()
    if not recvStr:
        break
    if client.name:
        print("got something from "+client.name+" on "+str(sock))
        print("Clients:")
        for client in self.clients:  # You're stomping on it here
            print(client.name)
        # Now when you use client below, its whatever came last in the for loop.
        print("this client is: "+str(index)+" - "+self.clients[index].name+" aka "+client.name)
```

Just use a different name in the for loop.